# Reading files using system.io?

Tags: c#, file, command-line, directory, .net

Could do with some help with this question.I am using the system.io, and I have to do things which require files to be moved, grouped, renamed.   .

Working in command line application using c# so far I have moved some files from one directory to another, I now need to group some pdf files like so  - B-12345 1.pdf, B-12345 2.pdf, B-12345 3.pdf, B-12345 4.pdf.I have been told I dont need to physically group them together just for the purposes of ensuring I only create one job per project reference(b-1234).

To give you a bit of background info on what im doing after these files are grouped I need to create a record in the job table sql database.But thats another question for another day just thought id give you some more info.

**Mainly I just need info on how to read files that are in a file directory and grouping files, this would be very beneficial to me.?**

To make the question a bit clearer this is the order in tasks should be done in the command line app.

1. Read files in directory (I have moved them so unsure on this?)
2. Group by project no (unsure)
3. Create job record in sql db
4. Move and rename file to correct location

Thanks in advance

My code is below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

public class MoveForProcessing
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // move cad jobs to processing directory and delete former folder, use the System.IO.Path class.
        System.IO.Directory.Move(@"C:\Users\Ben\My Documents\Temp\", @"C:\Users\Ben\My Documents\Processing\");
    }
}
```

Comment: What specifically are you asking? You are unlikely to find someone who will complete your project for you. Stack Overflow is there to find help with specific stuff.

Comment: Your question seems well thought out. I like how you break the process down in steps. If you tried to break down step 2 in a similar fashion you'd be a lot closer to finding the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could first declare a DirectoryInfo class of the dirctory in question

```
private System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = System.IO.DirectoryInfo.Open(@"path");
```

Then get an array of FileInfo objects for each file in the directory

```
private FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
```

You could also put a wildcard string into GetFiles() if you want only certain file types

```
private FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles("*.pdf");
```

Then you can increment through the array doing whatever you need with each FileInfo object

```
foreach(FileInfo f in files)
{
   f.Move(); // or whatever you need to do
}
```

Comment: This sounds right thanks, which piece of code would the grouping occur?

Comment: I would suspect in the foreach loop. You could test f.FileName for whatever criteria to move or copy or whatever you need to do with that file. If you need to group, you could create a List<FileInfo> object for each group, and as you step through the files, place the FileInfo into the correct List<> object, then foreach through those List<> objects to move or copy or whatever. Your choice.

Comment: Or if your grouping would allow, you could use different wildcards in the initial GetFiles() call, like maybe "B-1234*.pdf" and then all those move to the right sub directory, or whatever your action requires

Comment: where would the code provided go in my application Wanabrutbeer?

Comment: Oh, well right inside your Main() method, you could Console.WriteLine() inside the loop to provide some progress feedback to the command line, or if you are using a form, make a button and put this inside the button click handler. You could use a BackgroundWorker to do the job too, placing the code in the DoWork handler, and then you could access the ProgressChanged event to keep up with progress.